# Is there a tool that displays the common 3-column hex editor output to standard out?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, hexidecimal

I've been using `od` to display the contents of binary files in various formats. Often times I find myself bouncing between `-x` (hex output) and `-c` (ASCII output) at the same offsets, when I'd really like to see them side-by-side, like in a common hex editor. Are there any tools that print this style output, with similar options (skip, count, etc.) as `od`, to standard out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BSD Hexdump (package `bsdmainutils` on Ubuntu):

```
hexdump -C -s SKIP -n COUNT FILENAME
```